# Exception "No Private Key" - X509Store vs. Request.ClientCertificate?

Tags: asp.net, x509certificate

What is the difference between selecting a certificate via X509Store vs. Request.ClientCertificate?

I can sign a PDF from a certificate selected using X509Store.

```
 X509Store store = new X509Store(StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
 store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
 X509CertificateCollection certificates = X509Certificate2UI.SelectFromCollection(store.Certificates,
                                                                                        "Certificate Connections",
                                                                                        "Please select a certificate to sign with",
                                                                                        X509SelectionFlag.SingleSelection);
 store.Close();

 X509Certificate2 cert = null;

 if (certificates.Count != 0)
 {
      cert = (X509Certificate2)certificates[0];
      Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser cp = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();
      Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { cp.ReadCertificate(cert.RawData) };
      IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA-1");
     // .... REST OF CODE ....
 }
```

However, I cannot execute the same code on a certificated from Request.ClientCertificate, I always receive exception "No Private Key".

Here is the code used in both instances:

```
 X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2(Page.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate);

 if (Request.ClientCertificate.IsValid || Request.ClientCertificate.Count > 0)
 {         
      Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser cp = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509CertificateParser();
      Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] chain = new Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate[] { cp.ReadCertificate(cert.RawData) };
      IExternalSignature externalSignature = new X509Certificate2Signature(cert, "SHA-1");
      // .... EXCEPTION happens on line above ....
      // .... REST OF CODE ....
 }
```

Can anyone help on this?

Comment: Please see below, you will need the client certificate to contain the private key to sign anything. The `Page.Request.ClientCertificate.Certificate` would give you the certificate used for SSL which does not contain the private key. It cannot be done this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Client certificates presented to the server are a proof the client is who he claims he is (sorta) and this contains only the public key.

To sign something, you need to posses the private key, which only the client should have.
If you want to sign a document *on behalf of the client* you will need to *be* the client, or at least have his private key.

The X509Store is at the server, and usually contains the server certificates which do contain private key so the server can prove to others he is who he claims he is.

This is an over simplified explanation and not accurate enough to be considered a good one in my opinion - so i really urge you to learn more about PKI and certificates in general. I wrote a [post](http://blog.boxofbolts.com/ssl/windows/owin/guide/2015/06/29/https-self-hosted-windows/) trying to give a good background to beginners.

Comment: I have up-voted and accepted your answer, thanks for that!

Answer (score 1):

When making a web request, the client may optionally choose to send a certificate to prove their identity.  That's what Request.ClientCertificste is.  It probably won't ever include the private key part though as anyone with that could pass themselves off as the entity the certificate represents.  That would be really bad.

The store is the server machines store of certificates.  Some will only have pubic keys and are a list of identities the computer trusts.  Others are created locally by the computer or its users to prove they are in fact the computer or user they are claiming.  They will have private and public keys.  The public key is used by others to verify  that it was you or your computer that actually sent something.  The private keys should be kept private, as you use that to sign or encrypt data.  Read more here http://www.entrust.com/what-is-pki/